# Arangodb connection refused error # 61

Tags: arangodb

im very new with arango, but when i try to start the server with arangosh i get this

__ _ _ __ __ _ _ __   __ _  **_  _**| |__
 / *`| '__/ _` | '* \ / _` |/ _ / **| '_ \ 
| (*| | | | (*| | | | | (*| | (*) __ \ | | |
 __,*|*|  __,*|*| |*|_*, |_**/|***/*| |*|
                       |***/

arangosh (ArangoDB 3.3.3 [darwin] 64bit, using jemalloc, VPack 0.1.30, RocksDB 5.6.0, ICU 58.1, V8 5.7.492.77, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017)
Copyright (c) ArangoDB GmbH

Pretty printing values.
Could not connect to endpoint 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529', database: '_system', username: 'root'
Error message: 'Could not connect to 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' 'connect() failed with #61 - Connection refused''

using the newest version

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the arangod server is not running on the same machine (127.0.0.1) on port 8529.
Can you verify it is actually running, and its port number is actually 8529? This is the default port, but it can be adjusted in the server configuration file (arangod.conf).

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because arangoDB server is not running. In macOS You have to start server by running this command.

```
/usr/local/sbin/arangod &.
```